Issue with wxWidgets, CMake, and MSYS2: "libwx_mswu-3.2.a" not found during build with Ninja
I am facing a frustrating issue when trying to compile a C++ project using wxWidgets, CMake, and MSYS2 on Windows. Although CMake configures the project correctly and finds all the necessary libraries, I get the following error when trying to build with Ninja:
ninja: error: '/mingw64/lib/libwx_mswu-3.2.a', needed by 'bin/wxwidget-template.exe', missing and no known rule to make it

Environment details:

Operating System: Windows
MSYS2 Installation: D:/msys64
Compiler: MinGW-w64 (g++ and gcc)
wxWidgets: 3.2.5 (compiled in monolithic mode)
CMake: 3.26.0
Generator: Ninja

Commands used to configure and compile wxWidgets:
../configure --enable-optimise --enable-stl --enable-unicode --disable-shared --enable-monolithic
make
make install

Command used to configure CMake in the project:
I use principally VS Code, but also tried to do it in the MSYS2 Console and got the same.
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=D:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=D:/msys64/mingw64 -DwxWidgets_ROOT_DIR=D:/msys64/mingw64 -DwxWidgets_LIB_DIR=D:/msys64/mingw64/lib -DwxWidgets_CONFIGURATION=msw-unicode-static-3.2 -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON -G "Ninja" ../../..
CMake configuration output:
-- wxWidgets found: 3.2.5
-- wxWidgets include dirs: /mingw64/lib/wx/include/msw-unicode-static-3.2;/mingw64/include/wx-3.2
-- wxWidgets libraries: -L/mingw64/lib;;;-Wl,--subsystem,windows;-mwindows;/mingw64/lib/libwx_mswu-3.2.a;-limm32;-lwxtiff-3.2;-lwxjpeg-3.2;-lwxpng-3.2;-lwxregexu-3.2;-lwxscintilla-3.2;-lwxexpat-3.2;-lz;-lz;-lrpcrt4;-loleaut32;-lole32;-luuid;-luxtheme;-lwinspool;-lwinmm;-lshell32;-lshlwapi;-lcomctl32;-lcomdlg32;-ladvapi32;-lversion;-lws2_32;-lgdi32;-loleacc;-lwinhttp
-- Configuring done (9.7s)
-- Generating done (0.1s)

Error when runnig "ninja":
ninja: error: '/mingw64/lib/libwx_mswu-3.2.a', needed by 'bin/wxwidget-template.exe', missing and no known rule to make it
"CMakeLists.txt" file:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(wxwidget-template LANGUAGES CXX)

if (DEFINED DEVEL AND NOT DEVEL EQUAL 0)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Werror")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wextra")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Weffc++")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pedantic")
endif()

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

set(wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR "D:/msys64/mingw64")
set(wxWidgets_LIB_DIR "D:/msys64/mingw64/lib")
set(wxWidgets_LIBRARIES "D:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libwx_mswu-3.2.a")
set(wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS "D:/msys64/mingw64/include/wx-3.2;D:/msys64/mingw64/include;D:/msys64/mingw64/lib/wx/include/msw-unicode-static-3.2")
set(wxWidgets_CONFIGURATION "msw-unicode-static-3.2")

link_directories(D:/msys64/mingw64/lib)

find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED COMPONENTS monolithic)

if (wxWidgets_FOUND)
  message(STATUS "wxWidgets found: ${wxWidgets_VERSION_STRING}")
  message(STATUS "wxWidgets include dirs: ${wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
  message(STATUS "wxWidgets libraries: ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES}")
  include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})
else()
  message(FATAL_ERROR "wxWidgets not found!")
endif()

add_subdirectory("src")

"src/CMakeLists.txt" file:
include_directories(.)
include("${wxWidgets_USE_FILE}")

file(GLOB sources *.cpp)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} WIN32 ${sources})

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)

I already verified that the libwx_mswu-3.2.a file exists in D:/msys64/mingw64/lib. I suspected that the issue might be related to how ninja interprets the library paths, especially due to the mix of Unix and Windows paths, so i tryed using Unix Makefiles as generator and build with command make, but got the same error. However, I'm not sure how to resolve this.
I appreciate any help or suggestions you can offer. Thank you in advance!
Im trying to compile a wxWidgets project using CMake but i got an error at building with Ninja or make.

just BTW - you can simplify the configuiring wxWidgets by 1. removing --enable-unicode - it is enabled by default since version 3.0 and 2. removing --enable-monolithic, as it make sense for CodeBlocks developers only.. Finally you should update your CMakwe version as with latest wxWidgets the latest CMake thingy is strongly preferred.

Why not use pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-wxWidgets3.2?
